# Launch ClickOnce installer from ASP.NET MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, clickonce

I have a ASP .NET MVC website and in a folder, I have a ClickOnce Deployment of a WPF application.

So I create a "Publish" cshtml view, and from here I would like to open my ".application" file to install my application.

my link :

```
<form action="~/ClickOnceInstaller/MyApplication.application">
     <input type="submit" value="Install application">
</form>
```

But when I click on the link, it navigates to a white page. I have to click on the address bar and type enter to launch the installation.

Any idea ?

I tried with a simple .html page and it works with :

```
window.location.href = "./ClickOnceInstaller/MyApplication.application";
```

Answer (score 1):

The Link in the view

```
@Html.ActionLink("Download App", "Download", "Home")
```

For the Action

```
public ActionResult Download()
        {
            string path = @"~/Downloads/MyApplication.exe.manifest";
            string content = "application/x-ms-application";
            return new FilePathResult(path,content); 

        }
```

Comment: Is there a way to pass parameters to the ClickOnce installer using syntax "MyApplication.application?param=value" without getting a "Illegal characters in path." error ?

Comment: When you make the ClickOnce in Manifest make sure that "Allow URL parameters to be passed to application" has been checked. Then you should be able to pass a QueryString to it.